# On work done by motion of objects in elliptic orbits

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, orbital-motion

In uniform circular motion, the force is perpendicular to the instantaneous direction of motion. So work done is zero. But if an object is in elliptical orbit such as a planet, I find it hard to understand how the force is perpendicular to direction of motion. And if it is not, some work is done which also doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Why doesn't make sense? Work is done by gravitational force.

Comment: @Anusha yes. Net work done is zero was what I was thinking. But positive and negative work cancel out... The conservative force answer below is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the planet is getting closer to the Sun, the Sun is doing positive work on it. When it is getting farther from the Sun, the Sun is doing negative work on it. Over a complete orbit, the net work done is zero.

Answer (score 2):

1. The planets moving around the sun have elliptical orbits. That means that the force is not perpendicular to the velocity, so work is done by the sun's gravitational force is not zero; the planet will speed up and slow down depending on whether the planet is moving away from (slowing down) or toward (speed up) the sun.
2. The force is a central (radially-directed) force. That means that the gravitational force cannot change the angular momentum of the system. The angular momentum depends on the planet mass (m), speed (v), distance to sun (r), and the angle ($\theta$) between the radial and velocity directions:
   $$|\vec{L}|=mvr\cos\theta.$$

Both the work and the constancy of angular momentum happen simultaneously and in balance so the the work changes the speed in balance with the angle and distance change.

Because the work done on the planet is a conservative force we can express that work in terms of changes in a potential energy function which allows us to keep a constant mechanical energy (potential + kinetic).

One example of this is that at the perihelion, the kinetic energy is the largest and potential energy is smallest (most negative). At the aphelion, the kinetic energy is the smallest and potential energy is largest (least negative). And the angular momentum at both points are the same.
$$\frac{1}{2}mv_p^2-\frac{GmM_s}{r_p}=\frac{1}{2}mv_a^2-\frac{GmM_s}{r_a} \\
m v_p r_p = m v_a r_a$$

Answer (score 1):

If all forces are conservative (like the gravitational force), the work done on a closed path is zero, even if the forces are not all the time perpendicular to the trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

The force is not perpendicular to the direction of motion and work is done. This work goes into change of kinetic energy of the orbiting object - when it is closer to the gravity source, it moves faster. Another way of speaking about this work is though gravitational potential energy - the difference of potential energies in point 1 and point 2 is equal to the work done by gravitational field when the object moves from point 1 to point 2 (in any trajectory connecting these points).